# get paragraphs from XWPFSDT

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

Currently I get my coverpage content like :

```
if (document.getBodyElements().get(0) instanceof XWPFSDT) {
            XWPFSDT coverpageObj = (XWPFSDT) document.getBodyElements().get(0);
```

With this I can't get paragrpahs from coverpageObj this not works:

```
coverpageObj.getBody().getParagraphs()
```

And get me NullPointerException.

How can I get paragraphs from XWPFSDT ?

ps: i need paragraphs to retrieve relationId of an image

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to help with this kind of problems further because of the lack of an `API` documentation for the underlying `org.openxmlformats.schemas...` objects of `apache poi`. Earlier there was [grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTSdtBlock.java) or [atetric.com](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTSdtBlock.html). Both are not reachable for months now.

Comment: Only possibility would be getting [ooxml-schemas-1.3-sources.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/ooxml-schemas/1.3/ooxml-schemas-1.3-sources.jar) and do `javadoc` our own. Sorry but fault here is `apache poi` because of it's bad documentation.

Comment: dear Axel Richter, I already have this dependcy on my maven repo, and I still an't access to XWPFSDT  paragraphs, how you acces to it using ooxml-schemas, any docs ? thanks

Comment: You have not understood my comments? There **are no** docs about `ooxml-schemas` available any more (formerly leastways third party docs were available). That is the problem. So we are at a lost here now without any docs provided from `apache poi`.